# when to use *tria* vs. *tres* and why?

Tags: vocabulary

"Quot liberi in familia sunt? ____[III] liberi."
"*Vir*, *puer*, *puella* ____[III] vocabula sunt."
"Rhenus et Danuvius et Tiberis ____[III] fluvii sunt."

#when would I use tres vs. trio & why?

Answer (score 5):

It's a difference of gender. *Trēs* is used for the masculine and feminine, and *tria* for the neuter.

So in this case, what are the genders of *liberī*, *vocabula*, and *fluviī*?

Comment: *Liberī*=masculine, *vocabula*=neuter, fluvii=masculine
so 
"Quot liberi in familia sunt? Tres[III] liberi." 
"Vir, puer, puella tria[III] vocabula sunt." "Rhenus et Danuvius et Tiberis tres[III] fluvii sunt."